# how to show a component on specific pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I want to show a `navbar` whenever user is logged in

when ever user presses login button i replace the page with home page

i've tried to define use state and on condition of if path name is not equal to `/login` or `/step-two` set it to true then in the app i said if usestate was equal by true show the navbar

**but i don't see navbar until i refresh the page**

here is what i have tried in useeffect

```
  const [hasNavBar, setNavBar] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(history.location.pathname);
    if (history.location.pathname !== '/login'|| history.location.pathname !=='/step-two'
    ) {
      setNavBar(true)
    }
  }, [])
```

here is the whole code

```
    const App = () => {
      const [hasNavBar, setNavBar] = useState(false)
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(history.location.pathname);
        if (history.location.pathname !== '/login' ||
          history.location.pathname !== '/step-two'
        ) {
          setNavBar(true)
        }
      }, [])
      return (
        <div>
          <SNackbar></SNackbar>
          <Router history={history}>
            <div>
              <Route path="/login" exact component={FirstLogin} />
              <Route path="/step-two" exact component={SecondLogin} />
              <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path='/ranking-list' exact component={RankingListPage} />
            </div>
          </Router>
          <div>
          {hasNavBar ?
            <div>
              <BottomNavBar />
            </div> : ''
          }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    };
    
    export default App;
```

## update

i tried to use history.listen  bu still i see the same error

```
const App = () => {
  const [hasNavBar,setnavbar]=useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen(()=>{
      if (history.location.pathname === '/'||history.location.pathname === '/steptwo') {
        setnavbar(false);
      }else{setnavbar(true);}
        
      
    })
    if (localStorage.getItem("token") && history.location.pathname === '/') {
      history.replace('/home');
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <SNackbar></SNackbar>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={FirstLogin} />
          <Route path="/steptwo" exact component={SecondLogin} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/ranking-list' exact component={RankingListPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
      {hasnavbar?
       <div 
       style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px', width: "100%", height: '80px' }}>
        <BottomNavBar />
      </div>:''
      }
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: try to replace `{hasnavbar?` with `{hasNavBar?` because it has different with your usestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @lissettdm said

you need to use `history.listen` to call an function whenever history changes
but no need to Wrap App inside Router

if you don't use `history.listen` usestate only would change whenever you refresh the page as the useeffect would be run on refresh

you could define its default to false and whenever it is not in the condition it would be true a else statement so that whenever you change the route it would be called and make hasnavbar to true

```
  const [hasnavbar,setnavbar]=useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen(()=>{
      if (history.location.pathname === '/login'||history.location.pathname === '/steptwo') {
        setnavbar(false);
      }else{setnavbar(true);}   
    })
  }, [])
```

here is the whole code

```
const App = () => {
  const [hasnavbar,setnavbar]=useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen(()=>{
      if (history.location.pathname === '/login'||history.location.pathname === '/steptwo') {
        setnavbar(false);
      }else{setnavbar(true);}    
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <SNackbar></SNackbar>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={FirstLogin} />
          <Route path="/steptwo" exact component={SecondLogin} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/ranking-list' exact component={RankingListPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
      {hasnavbar?
       <div>
        <BottomNavBar />
      </div>:''
      }
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: i just got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Wrap App inside Router component and listen for history changes:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
 return history.listen(location => {
   if (
    history.location.pathname !== "/login" &&
    history.location.pathname !== "/step-two"
   ) {
     setNavBar(true);
   }
  });
}, []);
```

See working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5xd5d1?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Can i use multiple useeffects? because the current useeffect does multiple actions so i think i should different one for this

Comment: Yes you can use multiples useEffect.

Comment: I tried that, i got same result , again i should refresh the page to see the result

Comment: Can you check if every time the route changes this useEfffect is executed?

Comment: you mean in dependency? if yes, i checked it and i made sure i passed the `[history.location.pathname]` and still the same, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: See the updates, also I think this       window.location.pathname !== "/login" ||
      window.location.pathname !== "/step-two", should be       window.location.pathname !== "/login" &&
      window.location.pathname !== "/step-two"

Comment: i still got the same , you thing would be better if i use redux for that?

Comment: You should wrap the App inside Router.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `useEffect`'s logic from `||` to `&&`, right now it doesn't make sense.
2. Try to use a `useLocation` hook instead:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

let location = useLocation();

...

if (location.pathname !== '/login' && location.pathname !== '/step-two') { ... }
```

Comment: `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` this error shows up